# Найти размеры сторон наклоненного прямоугольника

Tags: математика, геометрия

Я знаю две точки: левый верхний (x1, y1) и правый нижний (x2, y2) угол прямоугольника, также знаю угол наклона прямоугольника в градусах (также знаю точку pivot/origin наклона). Каким образом найти длину сторон? Мне нужны конкретные формулы для рассчета ширины и высоты.

Подозреваю что тут что-то очень простое, но что-то никак не соображу.

Comment: Можете показать это в виде формулы или функции (на любом языке) где входящие аргументы - две точки и угол наклона прямоугольника, а результат - размеры сторон.

Comment: Поверни систему координат матрицей поворота и сразу будет ответ. Завтра напишу , если не забуду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пусть неизвестные ширина и высота прямоугольника `w` и `h`

Из картинки можно увидеть, что разница левой и правой координат `H.x` и `F.x`, в ваших обозначениях, вероятно, `x2-x1 = dx`

```
dx = h * s + w * c
```

где `c = Cos(Fi), s = Sin(Fi)`

А разница по ординате

```
dy = h * c - w * s
```

Если домножить первое уравнение на `s`, а второе на `с`, и сложить, то получим выражение для `h`

А если домножить первое уравнение на `с`, а второе на `s`, и вычесть, то получим выражение для `w`

Есть тонкости со знаками и тем, что считать шириной и высотой, но для `Fi<Pi/2` всё просто.

Comment: @posix Ну что, разобрались? Выражения получаются точно такие же, как при использовании матрицы поворота.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, я разобрался.

Comment: @posix Тогда не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer для подходящего ответа

Answer (score 0):

Преобразованием координат можно получиь сразу длинну и ширину.

Сначала сдвинем систему координат в точку 1. Получается 2 точки:

```
(0,0) и (x0,y0)=(х2-х1, у2-у1)
```

Потом повернем оси на угол a=-pivot, так как одна точка в (0,0) стоит, а стороны легли на оси - противоположная точка какраз ширина и высота прямоугольника

```
w = x0*cos(a)-y0*sin(a)
h = x0*sin(a)+y0*cos(a)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.